# Virgola dopo sintagma preposizionale iniziale

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Un mio amico mi ha chiesto se secondo me andava bene il suo inivito di nozze. Ho un dubbio sulla seguente frase:

> Dopo la cerimonia, saremo lieti di festeggiare presso il ristorante [...]

Quella virgola dopo il sintagma preposizionale iniziale (in questo caso un complemento di tempo) sicuramente si usa spesso, ma io la eviterei. È più corretto usarla o no?

Comment: Per me, entrambe frasi sono corrette. La virgola cambia l'enfasi.

Comment: Toglierei la virgola perché gli sposi parlano in prima persona, la lascerei se la frase fosse: Dopo la cerimonia, gli sposi saranno lieti..."

Comment: Si tratta di una frase con una struttura simile a quella proposta su [questo sito web](http://www.corriere.it/Rubriche/Scioglilingua/2006/19maggio.shtml) (vedi la sezione "Virgole"): complemento di tempo + (soggetto) + verbo. La risposta che il linguista Giorgio De Rienzo ne dà là (per la frase "Il 14 maggio 2006, il centro di formazione di Zurigo ha festeggiato il 50° anniversario") è: *l’inserimento della virgola nella frase che lei propone è opportuno, ma non obbligatorio*.

Comment: @JoeTaras: Cosa c'entra la virgola con la persona del verbo della frase?

Comment: Si tratta di una questione di stile e di preferenze personali. Non si capisce perché l'OP eviterebbe la virgola, in ogni caso entrambe le scelte sono grammaticalmente corrette. Personalmente la lascerei. Btw, auguri agli sposi!!

Comment: @Gio: forse eviterei la virgola perché la lingua che più ho imparato a scuola è il tedesco, e in tedesco le virgole sono regolate dalla grammatica tanto quanto la struttura della frase. Le virgole usate come se fossero dei marcatori di prosodia (di cui a volte si sente la mancanza, ma per i quali non è mai stato sviluppato un sistema, che dovrebbe essere molto più complesso dei pochi segni di interpunzione che usiamo) non mi piacciono. Per fortuna non sono l'unico a trovare orrende le virgole usate per separare il soggetto dal predicato, per fare un esempio.

Comment: @WalterTross - allora non metterla, :)

Comment: Confronta *Ieri sono andato al cinema* e *Dopo la cerimonia andremo a gozzovigliare*: non metterei mai la virgola. Metterla nel tuo caso è una scelta lecita perché la frase è più complessa (la tua abitudine al tedesco vorrebbe una virgola dopo *lecita*, suppongo).

Answer (score -1):

Si tratta di una scelta di puro stile, spesso dettata dal tono con cui si formulerebbe la frase vocalmente. È diffuso e liberamente interpretabile nella lingua italiana.

Comment: Potresti dare una risposta un po' più articolata, magari menzionando qualche fonte? Così com'è, è simile ai commenti già presenti sotto la domanda.

Comment: Certamente. Qui trovi indicazioni generali sull'uso della punteggiatura con alcune regole "fisse" ed altre un po' meno rigide (tra cui rientra la tua domanda). http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/punteggiatura

Comment: Grazie. Se pensi che ci sia qualcosa utile a integrare la tua risposta, usalo per integrare la tua risposta.

Comment: Di nulla, anzi integro per approfondimento un contenuto specifico al link http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/casi-dubbi-nella-prontuario-punteggiatura_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/. Al punto 2 trovi alcuni esempi pratici legati all'uso della punteggiatura con sintagmi di vario tipo. Vale la regola generale di non separare l'unità sintattica, ma ci sono alcune eccezioni letterarie, e più utilizzate. In particolare, per mia personale esperienza, accetterei l'uso della virgola nel caso citato. Un esempio sintattico anticonvenzionale è la scrittura di José Saramago.

Comment: Nell'articolo della Treccani che citi non c'è alcun caso analogo a quello della mia domanda, né, mi pare, alcuna regola utile a dirimere la questione.

Comment: Lo stesso mi pare si possa dire di quello dell'Accademia della Crusca. Ma poi perché, se a te questi articoli paiono rilevanti, non li inserisci nella risposta come ti ha suggerito @DaG?

Answer (score -1):

Secondo me la virgola è incorretta. 
Non c'è nessuna regola di grammatica che giustifichi una virgola in questa frase.
Dì al tuo amico di toglierla e fagli tanti auguri! :)

http://grammatica-italiana.dossier.net/punteggiatura.htm